# Change in the values of global variables not immediately updated?

Tags: global-variables, julia

In the following code, I tried to modify all the global variables (`s`,`t`,`u`,`v`) from within a function `test()`. Because `u` and `v` are inside a module, `Mod.u` and `Mod.v` are read-only variables, so I tried to change their values via setter functions (`set_u` and `set_v`).

```
s = 1
const t = 2

module Mod
u = 3
const v = 4

set_u( u_ ) = ( global u ; u = u_ )
set_v( v_ ) = ( global v ; v = v_ )
end

function test()
    global s, t

    s = "S" ; t = 200
    @show s, t

    Mod.set_u( "U" ) ; Mod.set_v( 400 )
    @show Mod.u, Mod.v
end

test()
@show s, t
@show Mod.u, Mod.v
```

The result (obtained with Julia v0.4.0) is

```
WARNING: redefining constant t
(s,t) = ("S",2)                          # (1)
WARNING: redefining constant v
(Mod.u,Mod.v) = ("U",4)                  # (2)
(s,t) = ("S",200)                        # (3)
(Mod.u,Mod.v) = ("U",400)                # (4)
```

Here, (3) and (4) are my expected results (assuming `const` fixes only the type of variables). But I cannot understand why the value of `t` and `Mod.v` are not updated in (1) and (2). Am I making some big mistake or misunderstanding about changing the value of global variables...? Or is this because of some different mechanism of referring to global variables from inside or outside a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only constants that aren't getting "updated" within the body of the function are those you've marked `const`.

> (assuming `const` fixes only the type of variables)

This assumption is incorrect.  While Julia does allow you to change the values of `const` bindings, redefining `const` variables can definitely cause problems.  Notice that it is warning you that this isn't a good idea.

Here's a simple example that demonstrates what's happening:

```
julia> const t = 3
       f() = t
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_llvm f()

define i64 @julia_f_21636() {
top:
  ret i64 3
}

julia> t = 4
       @code_llvm f()
WARNING: redefining constant t

define i64 @julia_f_21636() {
top:
  ret i64 3
}
```

You don't need to be very proficient at reading LLVM IR to see that it's returning the integer 3 and doing no lookup. It saw that `t` was marked constant and used that information to optimize it when it compiled the function. Breaking `const` and changing the value of `t` won't cause `f` to be recompiled, so the old value is returned. The LLVM is more complicated for the non-constant global, but it's still very readable.  You can see that it's loading a value from somewhere:

```
julia> s = 2
       g() = s
       @code_llvm g()

define %jl_value_t* @julia_g_21649() {
top:
  %0 = load %jl_value_t** inttoptr (i64 4417498392 to %jl_value_t**), align 8
  ret %jl_value_t* %0
}
```

In short: if you lie about the `const`-ness of your variables, you shouldn't be surprised when Julia gives you an old answer.

Comment: Ah, okay, now I understand... I was always assuming that `const` fixes only the type of variables (because it allows changing the values), but this seems to be dangerous because code compilation exploits the assumed constness... I was trying to use const global variables in Julia modules as "modifiable parameters" in a simulation (following a popular way in Fortran modules), but this seems not a good idea. Thanks very much :)

Comment: Just tested using `const t=[3]` as a pragmatic work-around to LLVM's optimization. the type information gets preserved: `typeof(t[1])==Int64` and the content can be changed. Again, this is a work-around, but it works.

Comment: @user3580870 Hi, I have just also confirmed that your approach works. Also, it seems that one can use the same trick for const, global composite types (i.e., Any does not propagate while its fields are still mutable). So such const global type may be useful for my purpose... But I will also try to think about more "julian" ways to store parameters rather than simply translating from other languages. Thanks :)